# How to use the IPA chart?

Tags: british-english, phonetics, word-stress, ipa, intonation

I've studied in English medium institutions all my life. However, now I'd like to brush up my intonation and pronunciation well before an IELTS exam.  I've got the IPA (International Phonetic Alphabet) chart and the Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary. Ok now what do I do? The pronunciation symbols in the dictionary don't seem to match with the IPA chart. I'm trying to learn the British system.

Comment: I don't think this is on-topic here, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Does the introduction to the dictionary tell you what system its pronunciation guides use?

Answer (score 2):

Oh I think I've solved the problem !  Not the introduction but they've written it in the back cover about following the IPA format. Though it might seem difficult to understand the actual sounds from the IPA chart it's now easy with widely available phonemic videos online.  Anyone can follow this sequence in learning the phonemes *(root sounds from which all words are pronounced in a language)* :

dictionary -> check IPA chart for individual sounds -> match them with the [phonemic chart video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxQUapA-2w4&t=1425s)   Thanks.

Comment: The *huge* problem with phonetics is they often rely on how you pronounce 'this letter in that word'… yet every accent & dialect pronounces *that* word differently. Catch 22.